# How do I use document.addEventListener in Pug?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to create an app using NodeJS, Express, Pug and Mongodb. The app displays list of commercial banks and their location.
Now, I created another view(location.pug), where users can select their location from an option select dropdown. Once selected, banks within that location will be displayed.

I tried getting the selected option using

```
document.getElementById('selectedbank').addEventListener("change", function(e) { 
 console.log(e.target.value); 
});
```

but I get an error - "ReferenceError: document is not defined". Please, how do I get over this??

Comment: That javascript needs to be included within a `<script>` tag in a Pug template. It needs to run client-side in the browser. It seems like you included it in your node.js file. Node doesn't have a `document` object.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I added the script tag, but the error is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Now the problem has been fixed. It happened that I was calling the event listener in my server file. So, I had to create another JS file (for client-side activities). I now posted the result to my server using http request.

If you're not clear on this solution, you can contact me.
Thank you.